# Widening or automatic type conversion in Java; why is there a precision loss?

Tags: java, casting, precision

Take this code for example.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i = 41;
   long l = i*9/5;  //no explicit type casting required
   float f = i*9/5; //no explicit type casting required
   double d = i*9/5;    //no explicit type casting required
   double e = (double) i*9/5;
   System.out.println("Int value "+i);
   System.out.println("Long value "+l);
   System.out.println("Float value "+f);
   System.out.println("Double value "+d);
   System.out.println("Double value cast "+e);
  }
}
```

The target type is larger than the source type and hence no explicit casting is required but why is there a loss of precision? Why can't I get `d` and `f` as 73.8?

Comment: Because you're doing integer math **first**, then converting to a floating point type.

Comment: `9/5` is `1`...

Comment: just try `9.0/5.0`, at least for float and double (and still float and double do not have infinite precision)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Your suggestion did help me in getting the desired result without type casting. Thanks. I want to know the cause of this behaviour. Why is there a loss of precision? Could you please help in making me understand that?

Comment: if both operands of division (or other operations) are integer, java does integer arithmetic, that means, the result is also integer so `9/5 == 0`. If any operand is double, double arithmetic is done:

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Shouldn't 9/5 = 1, in case of integer arithmetic? 9/5=1.8, taking only integer part will be 1.

Comment: yes, it is 1, but cannot change comment now

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger How is double e = (double) i*9/5; different from double e = i*9.0/5.0;? Internally, is it the same?

Comment: not sure how they are compiled but I am pretty confident that the compiler writes the same bytecode in both cases: convert the integer value to double and use double literals for 9 and 5.